# Wordpress error when replacing local jQuery by externally-hosted

Tags: jquery, wordpress, enqueue

I'm trying to load jquery from CDN instead of loading natively with wordpress. In my functions.php I have done it like below, making sure it should only happen on the front-end:

```
function replace_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery2', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery2');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'replace_jquery');
```

nonetheless, when I try to log in the admin area, I get a bunch of error starting with:

```
Notice: wp_deregister_script was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. 
Do not deregister the <code>jquery</code> script in the administration area. 
To target the front-end theme, use the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code> hook. 
Please see <a href="https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. 
(This message was added in version 3.6.0.) in /app/public/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4204
```

Sometimes it does not throw this error, and sometimes it does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The PHP notice is pretty clear, IMHO: "Do not deregister the `jquery` script in the administration area. **To target the front-end theme, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.**"

Comment: @cabrerahector but that's what I'm saying: I specifically check `!is_admin()` for that purpose.

Comment: WordPress is telling you: "don't hook into `init` for this, use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead." (See the highlighted text from my previous comment?)

Comment: yeah, ok, I did not really that's what a hook meant :P. I'm fairly to this. Makes sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been dealt with so many times over the years, and actually it is quite duplicated but anyway I'll try to summarize/update the **"Best practice"** approaches.

**1.** [Do not replace the default WordPress jQuery](https://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) unless you really have to. If you really care about performance [you don't need jquery](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery)

**2.** Unless your theme or plugin does load jQuery, WordPress doesn't load it in the **front-end** area by default, usually we have to use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` to load it. So first of all, make sure that you have jQuery enqueued. Use this code snippet to check your enqueued scripts:

```php
// Show all enqueued scripts
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', function () {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_scripts[] = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
    var_dump($enqueued_scripts);
} );
```

**3.** Do not using the wrong action hook [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) for adding your scripts, you should use [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) instead.

> There are intentional safeguards in place to prevent critical admin scripts, such as jQuery core, from being unregistered. [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/)

**4.** Most of solutions to replace the default jquery are outdated. Use this code instead (Tested on WP v5.1):

```php
// Replace the default wp jquery with fallback
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_default_jquery_with_fallback');
function replace_default_jquery_with_fallback() {
    // Change the version if needed
    $ver = '1.12.4';
    // Dequeue first then deregister
    wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    // Load from Google
    // Set last parameter to 'true' if you want to load it in footer
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/$ver/jquery.min.js", '', $ver, false );
    // Fallback
    wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery', 'window.jQuery||document.write(\'<script src="'.includes_url( '/js/jquery/jquery.js' ).'"><\/script>\')' );
    wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery' );
}
```

**Please note that:**

- Using this way will also affect any plugin that depends on jQuery
- The correct way to completely remove a style or script is to **dequeue** it first then **deregister** it.
- [init](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) action hook is "Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent" use it with care.
- [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is used to handle **front-end** scripts.
- [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) is used to handle **admin scripts**.
- [login_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts) used for **login pages**.
- Consider using [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) if your code/plugins developed for jQuery versions older than 1.9.